# Recoil - TypeError: dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore is not a function

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I've found some posts that talk about this error in regards to [Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71925618/uncaught-typeerror-dispatcher-usesyncexternalstore-is-not-a-function) (where the issue is that Redux isn't supported with React 18), but not Recoil.

I'm able to add the RecoilRoot tag in and get everything to run properly, until I add useRecoilValue or useRecoilState, then I get this error:

[image: console error]

Here's my button.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { buttonActiveState, buttonDisabledState } from "../atoms";

function Button(props) {
  const isButtonDisabled = useRecoilValue(buttonDisabledState);
  const isButtonActive = useRecoilValue(buttonActiveState);
  return (
    <button
      className={getClassName(props, isButtonActive)}
      type="button"
      disabled={isButtonDisabled}
    >
      {props.copy}
    </button>
  );
}

function getClassName(props, buttonActiveState) {
  let className = "btn btn-primary ";
  if (props.className) {
    className += props.className;
  }
  if (buttonActiveState) {
    className += " active";
  }
  return className;
}

export default Button;
```

and the atoms.js

```
import { atom } from "recoil";

export const buttonActiveState = atom({
  key: "buttonActiveState",
  value: false,
});

export const buttonDisabledState = atom({
  key: "buttonDisabledState",
  value: false,
});
```

(RecoilRoot is wrapped around the content in the return statement for my main component)

I can't find anything about this online. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you can, would you replace the image of the error text with the text itself? You'll find that your console window will let you copy it to your clipboard. Images of text don't play so well with clipboards, screen-readers, and search-engine robots - text is nearly always better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are traces of `react-hot-reload` in your build, it can be found both in `webpack` config files and in the `babel` configuration as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32857777)